# Based on country selected , need to populate state and city

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-options

HTML:

```
<label for="country">Country *</label>
 <select id="country" ng-model="statessource" ng-options="country for (country, states) in countries"
                ng-change="GetSelectedCountry()">
 <option value=''>Select</option>
</select>    
 <label for="state">State *</label>
<select id="state" ng-disabled="!statessource" ng-model="model.state" ng-options="state for (state,city) in statessource"
         ng-change="GetSelectedState()"><option value=''>Select</option>
 </select>
  <label for="city">City *</label>
 <select id="city" ng-disabled="!citiessource || !statessource" ng-model="city"><option value=''>
  Select</option>
<option ng-repeat="city in citiessource" value='{{city}}'>{{city}}</option>
 </select>
```

JS:

```
$scope.countries = {

                'USA': {
                    'Alabama': ['Montgomery', 'Birmingham'],
                    'California': ['Sacramento', 'Fremont'],
                    'Illinois': ['Springfield', 'Chicago']
                },
               'India': {
                    'Maharashtra': ['Pune', 'Mumbai', 'Nagpur', 'Akola'],
                    'Madhya Pradesh': ['Indore', 'Bhopal', 'Jabalpur'],
                    'Rajasthan': ['Jaipur', 'Ajmer', 'Jodhpur']
                },
                'Australia': {
                    'New South Wales': ['Sydney'],
                    'Victoria': ['Melbourne']
                }
            };

 $scope.GetSelectedCountry = function () {
                $scope.strCountry = document.getElementById("country").value;
            };
            $scope.GetSelectedState = function () {
                $scope.strState = document.getElementById("state").value;
            };
```

I have written above JSON $sope.countries to populate State and city based on country.
My country and state field is populating perfectly, but my city is not having any item in it. Anyother solutions populating state and city based on selected country also will do good.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body data-ng-controller="testController">



  <label for="country">Country *</label>
  <select id="country" ng-model="countrySrc" ng-options="country for (country, states) in countries" ng-change="GetSelectedCountry()">
    <option value=''>Select</option>
  </select>
  <label for="state">State *</label>
  <select id="state" ng-disabled="!countrySrc" ng-model="stateSrc" ng-options="state for (state,city) in countrySrc" ng-change="GetSelectedState()">
    <option value=''>Select</option>
  </select>
  <label for="city">City *</label>
  <select id="city" ng-disabled="!countrySrc || !stateSrc" ng-model="city" ng-options="city for city in stateSrc">
    <option value=''>Select</option>

  </select>

  <script>
    angular
      .module('myApp', [])
      .run(function($rootScope) {
        $rootScope.title = 'myTest Page';
      })
      .controller('testController', ['$scope',
        function($scope) {


          $scope.countries = {

            'USA': {
              'Alabama': ['Montgomery', 'Birmingham'],
              'California': ['Sacramento', 'Fremont'],
              'Illinois': ['Springfield', 'Chicago']
            },
            'India': {
              'Maharashtra': ['Pune', 'Mumbai', 'Nagpur', 'Akola'],
              'Madhya Pradesh': ['Indore', 'Bhopal', 'Jabalpur'],
              'Rajasthan': ['Jaipur', 'Ajmer', 'Jodhpur']
            },
            'Australia': {
              'New South Wales': ['Sydney'],
              'Victoria': ['Melbourne']
            }
          };

          $scope.GetSelectedCountry = function() {
            $scope.strCountry = $scope.countrySrc;
          };
          $scope.GetSelectedState = function() {
            $scope.strState = $scope.stateSrc;
          };
        }
      ])
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Hope this solution helps.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, its good solution. My problem resolved

Comment: one more thing if I need to assign the values to my ng-model countrySrc by default as India ?? How its possible to do?

Comment: `$scope.countrySrc = $scope.countries["India"];` lets set this in controller.

Answer (score 0):

you need to call the cities from the states selected just like how your calling states from countries

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
    <label for="country">Country *</label>
 <select id="country" ng-model="statessource" ng-options="country for (country, states) in countries"
                ng-change="GetSelectedCountry()">
 <option value=''>Select</option>
</select>    
 <label for="state">State *</label>
<select id="state" ng-disabled="!statessource" ng-model="model.state" ng-options="state for (state,city) in statessource"
         ng-change="GetSelectedState()"><option value=''>Select</option>
 </select>
  <label for="city">City *</label>
 <select id="city" ng-disabled="!model.state" ng-model="model.city" ng-options="city for city  in model.state"
         ng-change="GetSelectedState()"><option value=''>Select</option>
 </select>
  </body>
```

[solved plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/q9YG1Ae6xagq6R3QHIfR?p=preview)